# Error sending data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I found that my disk is in full size for elasticsearch

Then, When I tried to run the command, it comes across with the following issues.

[Administrator@localhost elasticsearch]$ curator --host 172.16.1.245 delete indices --older-than 2 --time-unit days --timestring '%Y.%m.%d'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/curator", line 5, in 
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: See this: https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues/454

Comment: Why not just deleting the file in index directory in elasticsearch helps?

Comment: I advise against playing with the raw files on the filesystem. Either use curator properly or run use the `DELETE index` endpoint with a curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Val's comment, you can use :

```
curl -XDELETE 172.16.1.245:9200/_all
```

to delete all index, or

```
 curl -XDELETE 172.16.1.245:9200/index_name
```

to delete index one by one.